# Can't open "Settings" apps on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: command-line, application-development, 21.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 from Ubuntu 20.04.

It ran smoothly with no problems, and now I  couldn't open the "Settings."  How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and paste the command

```
gnome-control-center
```